# Converting Binary Float To Decimal On Paper. Mantissa begins with 0

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

Good afternoon all. I wasn't exactly sure where to post this question so I apologize if this is the wrong thread. I am currently taking a Discreet Mathematics course and initially I thought I understood binary float to decimal conversion rather well from a previous course. However today while doing some practice work using arbitrary sizes, I came across a problem that I must understand.

For the sake of easy math, I am going to use a 1 sign bit, 3 bit exponent (with a 4 bit bias instead of 127) and a 4 bit mantissa.

I have this number. 0 010 0100 Seems easy enough and it probably is to all you experts.

- I know the first bit 0 is the sign bit, this number is positive.
- I also know that the next 3 bits are the exponent bits. 010 represents 2. For this problem I am using a 4 bit bias instead of 127 so I do 2 - 4 = -2. I will shift the invisible decimal over to the left 2 spots on the Mantissa.

Here is my question. This mantissa starts with 0 instead of a 1. So is the "invisible" decimal point before or after that 1?

Basically what I am asking is, before shifting the decimal, is the mantissa 0.100 or 1.00 ? Oddly enough with all the floating point questions asked on exams from my previous classes, I don't believe I came across this problem. Perhaps the Professor's were being kind to us by giving us easy scenarios.

I always thought that the Mantissa is "normalized so I should see this Mantissa as 1.000 before shifting to the left twice to get .01000 which becomes .25 in decimal. But now I am not so sure.

Thanks for your time all!

Answer (score 2):

For normal float formats, there is an *implied* leading one which is not encoded in the mantissa bits. So your mantissa would actually be `1.0100` in binary.

for more info see [IEEE_754-1985](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)

Comment: You totally just rocked my world! That makes absolute sense. So when I am converting from decimal back to binary, that is why I move the decimal over to the first significant digit. Is that correct? I move the decimal to the left until there is a 1 in front of the decimal such as 1.010101011? Thanks so much. Now I fully understand why there is the implied leading one.